# Duplicate symbol found

Tags: ios, xcode, mailcore, libsmbclient

I have just imported MailCore2 into my project and I have followed all the steps that they have stated, but I am still getting an issue.

> duplicate symbol _hmac_md5_final in:
>
> ```
> XYZ/Debug-iphonesimulator/libetpan-ios.a(md5.o)
> ABC/libs/libsmbclient.a(hmacmd5.o)
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _hmac_md5 in:
>
> ```
> XYZ/Debug-iphonesimulator/libetpan-ios.a(md5.o)
> ABC/libs/libsmbclient.a(hmacmd5.o) ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
> ```

From what I can understand, _hmac_md5 and _hmac_md5_final appear in both of the files libetpan-ios.a * libsmbclient.a. In other posts people state that I need to remove one of the links or rename. I am using KxSMB and MailCore2 so I have no idea how to do any of these.

I have tried methods in other posts as much as I can follow them but:

- I don't understand where I need to go.
- I try them but end up getting far more errors.

Comment: Try to delete derived data. Go to Window - Projects, select your project and click Delete next to Derived Data label

Comment: Thanks, i have done this but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: There is no trivial way to solve this issue as both libraries have implemented the same functions.

Comment: so are you saying that there is no way around this? i have to abandon what i am doing and find another way?

Comment: If you were absolutely sure that the two implementations of those two functions were exactly the same and that they were the only functions needed from one of those .o files, it would be possible to delete that .o module from its .a archives using `ar -d` on the command line.  However, the probability of that breaking even more stuff is very high.

Comment: Thanks Phillip, i think that it will cause more issues if i delete one of the .o files so I'm going to look at a different way of doing it.

Comment: I think that I'd need to prefix the names of the functions in md5 (disclosure: I'm the maintainer of MailCore and libetpan). Could you file an issue in libetpan? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @DinhViêtHoà is there anyway that i can PM you? thanks.

Comment: Asking questions on stackoverflow is fine except if there are sensitive informations.

Comment: ok no worries, i have submitted an issue to libetpan.